# HTML complex tables

Tags: html

i want to;
    1.remove a small part of this table and make a free space there.i comennted it on the code.
    2.also to center the words in the table.
    CAN ANY ONE HELP ME PLEASE?(Please use only HTML not css or javascript)

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>My First Webpage</title>
    </head>

    <body >

    <table border="1px" width="80%" cellspacing="0" cellpading="0" > 

    <tr>
    <td ></td>        <! -- I NEED TO REMOVE THIS PART FROM TABLE AND MAKE A **FREE SPACE** HEARE -->

    <td >9-11</td>
    <td >11-13</td>
    <td >13-15</td>
    <td >15-17</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td >Monday</td>  
    <td>6</td>
    <td colspan="0">7</td>
    <td rowspan ="3">Lunch</td>
    <td>a</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Tuesday</td>  
    <td colspan="2">&#60; free</td>
    <td>s</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td >Wedensday</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>s</td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Removing an element requires JavaScript, formatting and aligning requires css.

Comment: Can you explain more why the space is being removed do you want the cells to get shifted up or stay as is? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: For non CSS, add attribute `<td align="center">` to the cells you want the text centered.

Comment: no no i don't want to shift the line to left by removing it.i just want to remove the small table and make a free space there.(i mean the small blank table)

Comment: bloodyKnuckles thank you :)

Comment: Are you saying you don't want borders around that table cell?

Comment: bloodyKnuckles,,  yes i mean only to that empty table.not to the whole table

Comment: if i delete that <td ></td> part table i cant get a free space in between "Monday" and "9-11" tables.

Answer (score 1):

It's best practice to use CSS for the centering. You could do it like this:

```
<table style="text-align:center">
```

But you could also use HTML in each cell like this:

```
<td align="center">Text</td>
```

or like this:

```
<td><center>Text</center></td>
```

Tables aren't meant to skip cells, so different browsers will handle it differently. You won't get consistent results. Depending on what you need the blank space for, though, there are some workarounds you could use.

If you just want the cell to be empty, put a sticky space inside like this:

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

Some browsers are confused by empty tags, but adding a sticky space (which displays as a space- you can't see it) fixes that.

If you want the cell to have no background / border, so it looks like it isn't there:

```
<td style="background:none; border:none">
```

That's embedded CSS, and I've included it because the HTML version is deprecated and you're really supposed to use CSS instead, but here's the HTML:

```
<td bgcolor="#000000" border=0>
```

You must replace #000000 with the color behind the table. If there's an image or text behind the table, you could use a transparent image as the background instead. (I wouldn't advise going to all that trouble if there's any way you can use style="background:none" instead, though.)

You could make the cell following the one you're removing span the space of both of them:

```
<td colspan=2>9-11</td>
<td >11-13</td>
<td >13-15</td>
<td >15-17</td>
```

Another solution is to put tables inside a table.

```
<table border="1px" width="80%" cellspacing="0" cellpading="0" >

    <tr>
        <td align="right"> <!-- The content is aligned to the right so that the blank space will be on the left. -->
            <table width="80%"> <!-- The width of four out of five cells is 80% of the total width -->
                <tr>
                    <td >9-11</td>
                    <td >11-13</td>
                    <td >13-15</td>
                    <td >15-17</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td >Monday</td>  
        <td>6</td>
        <td colspan="0">7</td>
        <td rowspan ="3">Lunch</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Tuesday</td>  
        <td colspan="2">&#60; free</td>
        <td>s</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td >Wedensday</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>s</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

As you can see, there are a ton of different ways to approach the problem. HTML leaves a lot of room for experimentation and creativity.

Comment: My pleasure. It's not a simple fix, but I hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

jF: http://jsfiddle.net/theStudent/b9tGV/1/

I would say you will have to use some CSS, that would be the most professional way to go about doing it.

I have started you off so you can see how that works in above link, it is quite simple and there is lot of tutorials and samples online just do little research.

Sample I started you with is very plain needs more work.

best of luck I believe that is a good start

HTML

My First Webpage

```
<body >

<table width="80%" cellspacing="0" cellpading="0" > 

<tr>
<td class="no-border"></td>        <! -- I NEED TO REMOVE THIS PART FROM TABLE AND MAKE A **FREE SPACE** HEARE -->

<td class="border">9-11</td>
<td class="border">11-13</td>
<td class="border">13-15</td>
<td class="border">15-17</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="border">Monday</td>  
<td>6</td>
<td colspan="0" class="border">7</td>
<td rowspan ="3" class="border">Lunch</td>
<td class="border">a</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="border">Tuesday</td>  
<td class="border" colspan="2">&#60; free</td>
<td class="border">s</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="border">Wedensday</td>
<td class="border">a</td>
<td class="border">s</td>
<td class="border">5</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.no-border{
    border: none;
}
.border{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Rather than adding class `border` to almost every cell it would be simpler to give the table an id and apply the border using `#tableid td`, and have a single instance of the `no-border` class to remove it (just for that cell).

Comment: You are welcome please do accept one of the two answers provided.. This busts your rating as well as the person that posted. @Qaz answer looks very good as well and informational.. Best of luck once again!

Comment: i'm new heare & i don't know how to accept them friend :(